# Comparing Columns Function

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function in Python that takes in two inputs:

- a single list from a list of lists (called row)
- a 2D array formatted as a list of lists (called A).

I want the function to find the first element of row and match it to the row in A that has the same first element.

Then the function should look to see if there is a zero in a particular column of "row" where there is not a zero in that same column for "A"

(for instance: there is a zero in the 5th column of row but a 26 in the 5th column of A).

If there is a mismatch, the function should print the row.

Below is the code I am working with, but I am getting a Index error saying the list index is out of range:

```
def compcols(row, A):
    for i in range(len (A)):
        for j in range(len(row)):
            if row[0]==A[i][0]:
                if row[j]==0 and A[i][j]!=0:
                    print row
```

Python specifically lists an error with the line  "if row[j]==0 and A[i][j]!=0:"

Comment: what error does it specify?

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this

```
def compcols(row, A):
    for i in A:
        if row[0]==i[0]:
            for j, k in zip(row, i):
                if j==0 and k!=0:
                    print row
```

Answer (score 0):

So you get a list index is out of range of that line `if row[j]==0 and A[i][j]!=0:`. `j` is by construction in `range(len(row))` so the error should not come from `row[j]`. On previous line, you allready have `if row[0]==A[i][0]:` so it should not come from A[i].

I suspect it comes from `A[i]` having less elements that `row`. You should add a test to be sure :

```
def compcols(row, A):
    for i in range(len (A)):
        if (len(A[i]) < len(row):
            raise Exception("Line %d len(A[i]) %d - len(row) %d"
                            % (i, len(A[i]), len(row)))
        for j in range(len(row)):
            if row[0]==A[i][0]:
                if row[j]==0 and A[i][j]!=0:
                    print row
```

Comment: You were right about A[i] having less elements than row (it has one fewer), however, when I tried using your modifications, I got the following error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    compcols(x, y)
  File "C:\Users\nbhambi\Desktop\AmgenProgram.py", line 15, in compcols
    if len(A[i]) < len(row):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: I thought `row` was a list (should have a len) and `A` a list of list so  `A[i]` should be a list ... What do you call compcols with ?

Comment: Never mind I was just being dumb. But it does print out row several times in the loop and when I try to take it out of one of the for loops, I get an unexpected indent error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe a mix of tabs and spaces if you copied and pasted code ?