# Finding Data Incongruities in 2D Arrays (Python)

Tags: python, arrays

Hey guys I'm working with a data set that has 14 columns (Department ID, Employee ID, and the months of the year) showing how many hours each employee worked for each month. The function I am working with needs to print out the row for employees who record a zero value for a particular month when his/her department (as a whole) recorded a non-zero value (i.e. John in Marketing recorded zero hours for May when the department total was 500 hours so we print John's row).  I have two helper functions: cost_center_sum(A) which takes in the 2D array of data (organized as a list of lists) and finds the cumulative hours for each department as a list of lists.  The second helper function, compcols(row, A), matches the department ID of "row" with the appropriate row in the data set A and checks to see if the zero value in "row" for a particular month corresponds to a zero for the same month in the row matched in A.  I tried compiling these two functions into the function, findgaps(A), which prints the employee information for an employee who records a zero for a month the department recorded a non-zero value.

Below is the code for the functions I described above:

```
def compcols(row, A):
for i in range(len(A)):
    if len(A[i]) < len(row):
        raise Exception("Line %d len(A[i]) %d - len(row) %d"
                        %(i, len(A[i]), len(row)))
    for j in range(len(row)):
        if row[0]==A[i][0]:
            if row[j]==0 and A[i][j]!=0:
                print row


NUMBER_OF_MONTHS = 12
def cost_center_sum(A):
    dep = dict()
    for row in A:
        if row[0] not in dep:
            dep[row[0]] = [0.0 for x in xrange(NUMBER_OF_MONTHS)]
        for i in xrange(NUMBER_OF_MONTHS):
            dep[row[0]][i] += row[i+2]
    ret = list()
    for department in sorted(dep.iterkeys()):
        x = [department]
        x.extend(dep[department])
        ret.append(x)
    return ret


def findgaps(A):
X = cost_center_sum(A)
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(A[0])):
            if A[i][j] < 0.00001:
                return compcols(A[i],X)
```

I have tested the other functions and they seem to do their job fairly well (there is a minor bug in compcol which prints out the same line several times), but when I use the findgaps function, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    findgaps(my_list)
  File "C:\Users\nbhambi\Desktop\AmgenProgram.py", line 38, in findgaps
    return compcols(A[i],X)
  File "C:\Users\nbhambi\Desktop\AmgenProgram.py", line 7, in compcols
    %(i, len(A[i]), len(row)))
Exception: Line 0 len(A[i]) 13 - len(row) 14
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - problem was much simpler pub was induced in error by [preceding post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393287/comparing-columns-function)

ALL THAT IS STUPID MESS

What happens is normal : `if len(A[i]) < len(row): raise Exception("...")` precisely throws an error if A[i] is shorter than row. I suppose you prefere the program to continue instead.

So here is what you could do (simple warning instead of error) :

```
def compcols(row, A):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if len(A[i]) < len(row):
            print row, (" - beware : line %d len(A[i]) %d < len(row) %d"
                            %(i, len(A[i]), len(row)))
        else:
            if row[0]==A[i][0]:
                for j in range(len(row)):
                    if row[j]==0 and A[i][j]!=0:
                        print row
                        break
```

I also added a break at the end of the innermost loop to print the `row` only once and pulled the test `row[0]==A[i][0]` outside of that loop to avoid useless tests.

BACK TO ACTUAL SOLUTION

Because of post cited above, I only tried to fix the Exception problem. But the problem was much simpler : by construction, `cost_center_sum` produces a list of **lists of size 13** that `findgaps` and then `compcols` compare to a list of size **14** ! In fact, if there were a single line in A having not 14 values, the error would occur in `cost_center_sum` that is called before `compcols`.

So to have all that work :

- `compcols` should compare **only month value and not first fields** in inner loop and get those values where they are :

  ```
  def compcols(row, A):
      for i in range(len(A)):
          if row[0]==A[i][0]:
              for j in range(1, len(row)):
                  if row[j]==0 and A[i][j + 1]!=0:
                      print row
                      break
  ```
- `findgaps` should stop calling `compcols` after a match :

  ```
  def findgaps(A):
      X = cost_center_sum(A)
      for i in range(len(A)):
          for j in range(len(A[0])):
              if A[i][j] < 0.00001:
                  compcols(A[i],X)
                  break
  ```

Comment: When I use the findgaps function, it still prints out 80 copies of the line: [10017.0, 93454.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.6, 0.0]  - beware : line 80 len(A[i]) 13 < len(row) 14.  Do you know why it still prints out several copies even with the break?

Comment: Also the findgaps function provides an incorrect answer, providing us the row of an employee whose data matches with the cumulative department data

Comment: For the 80 copies of the line *beware*, each call to `compcols` print one single line, but I think that `findgaps` calls `compcols` 80 times ... And for the second comment, are you speaking of that *beware* line ?

Comment: No, I mean the purpose of findgaps is that if an employee records zero hours for a month where his department records a non-zero value, that employee row gets printed.  The way my findgaps function is working right now, however, it's printing out a single employee line who records zero values where his department records zero values and non-zero values where his department records non-zero values

Comment: @user3758443 Could you show what is that line so I can try to reproduce problem ?